# Implementing GLCM texture feature with scikit-image and Python

Tags: python, textures, scikit-image, glcm

I am trying to implement a texture image as [described in this tutorial](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/texture_calculations.htm) using Python and skimage.

The issue is to move a 7x7 window over a large raster and replace the center of each pixel with the calculated texture from the 7x7 window. I manage to do this with the code below, but I see no other way than looping through each individual pixel, which is very slow.

One software package does that in a few seconds, so there must be some other way ... is there?

Here the code that works but is very slow ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gdal, gdalconst
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops

filename = "//mnt//glaciology//RS2_20140101.jpg"
outfilename = "//home//max//Documents//GLCM_contrast.tif"
sarfile = gdal.Open(filename, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)

sarraster = sarfile.ReadAsArray()
#sarraster is satellite image, testraster will receive texture
testraster = np.copy(sarraster)
testraster[:] = 0

for i in range(testraster.shape[0] ):
    print i,
    for j in range(testraster.shape[1] ):

        #windows needs to fit completely in image
        if i <3 or j <3:
            continue
        if i > (testraster.shape[0] - 4) or j > (testraster.shape[0] - 4):
            continue

        #Calculate GLCM on a 7x7 window
        glcm_window = sarraster[i-3: i+4, j-3 : j+4]
        glcm = greycomatrix(glcm_window, [1], [0],  symmetric = True, normed = True )

        #Calculate contrast and replace center pixel
        contrast = greycoprops(glcm, 'contrast')
        testraster[i,j]= contrast

sarplot = plt.imshow(testraster, cmap = 'gray')
```

Results:

[image: Contrast GLCM]

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Have not found a solution to your question.

Comment: Have you tried using numba?

Comment: Not 100% sure it's faster than your nested loop, but numpy.ndimage has a generic_filter function that provides a `footprint` sized window walking over an image and calculating the return via your provided function. Possibly you could combine these. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter

Comment: Looking at the source, the issue appears to be with the use of `symmetric = True` and `normed = True` which are performed in Python not Cython. For an 11x11 window, I get the following timings, first where both flags are `True`, then both `False`:

 `True:  29.3 ms ± 1.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`
 `False: 792 µs ± 16.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`, i.e. about 97% of the execution time is being taken up with the symmetric and normalisation operations.

Comment: Matt, this is such useful information, would you like to type up this investigation in a blog post somewhere? If you don't have anywhere, I invite you to publish it via our OpenPlanetary group's blog. https://www.openplanetary.org

Comment: ah you already did, at least in the GH issue. ;) thanks!

Comment: The link is 404.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, different data.  Here is a script I wrote that uses parallel processing and a sliding window approach:

```
import gdal, osr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as ast
import dask.array as da
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, cpu_count
import os
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops

def im_resize(im,Nx,Ny):
    '''
    resize array by bivariate spline interpolation
    '''
    ny, nx = np.shape(im)
    xx = np.linspace(0,nx,Nx)
    yy = np.linspace(0,ny,Ny)

    try:
        im = da.from_array(im, chunks=1000)   #dask implementation
    except:
        pass

    newKernel = RectBivariateSpline(np.r_[:ny],np.r_[:nx],im)
    return newKernel(yy,xx)

def p_me(Z, win):
    '''
    loop to calculate greycoprops
    '''
    try:
        glcm = greycomatrix(Z, [5], [0], 256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
        cont = greycoprops(glcm, 'contrast')
        diss = greycoprops(glcm, 'dissimilarity')
        homo = greycoprops(glcm, 'homogeneity')
        eng = greycoprops(glcm, 'energy')
        corr = greycoprops(glcm, 'correlation')
        ASM = greycoprops(glcm, 'ASM')
        return (cont, diss, homo, eng, corr, ASM)
    except:
        return (0,0,0,0,0,0)


def read_raster(in_raster):
    in_raster=in_raster
    ds = gdal.Open(in_raster)
    data = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    data[data<=0] = np.nan
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    xres = gt[1]
    yres = gt[5]

    # get the edge coordinates and add half the resolution 
    # to go to center coordinates
    xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
    xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
    ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
    ymax = gt[3] - yres * 0.5
    del ds
    # create a grid of xy coordinates in the original projection
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax+xres:xres, ymax+yres:ymin:yres]
    return data, xx, yy, gt

def norm_shape(shap):
   '''
   Normalize numpy array shapes so they're always expressed as a tuple,
   even for one-dimensional shapes.
   '''
   try:
      i = int(shap)
      return (i,)
   except TypeError:
      # shape was not a number
      pass

   try:
      t = tuple(shap)
      return t
   except TypeError:
      # shape was not iterable
      pass

   raise TypeError('shape must be an int, or a tuple of ints')

def sliding_window(a, ws, ss = None, flatten = True):
    '''
    Source: http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268#more-268
    Parameters:
        a  - an n-dimensional numpy array
        ws - an int (a is 1D) or tuple (a is 2D or greater) representing the size 
             of each dimension of the window
        ss - an int (a is 1D) or tuple (a is 2D or greater) representing the 
             amount to slide the window in each dimension. If not specified, it
             defaults to ws.
        flatten - if True, all slices are flattened, otherwise, there is an 
                  extra dimension for each dimension of the input.

    Returns
        an array containing each n-dimensional window from a
    '''      
    if None is ss:
        # ss was not provided. the windows will not overlap in any direction.
        ss = ws
    ws = norm_shape(ws)
    ss = norm_shape(ss)
    # convert ws, ss, and a.shape to numpy arrays
    ws = np.array(ws)
    ss = np.array(ss)
    shap = np.array(a.shape)
    # ensure that ws, ss, and a.shape all have the same number of dimensions
    ls = [len(shap),len(ws),len(ss)]
    if 1 != len(set(ls)):
        raise ValueError(\
        'a.shape, ws and ss must all have the same length. They were %s' % str(ls))

    # ensure that ws is smaller than a in every dimension
    if np.any(ws > shap):
        raise ValueError(\
        'ws cannot be larger than a in any dimension.\
     a.shape was %s and ws was %s' % (str(a.shape),str(ws)))

    # how many slices will there be in each dimension?
    newshape = norm_shape(((shap - ws) // ss) + 1)


    # the shape of the strided array will be the number of slices in each dimension
    # plus the shape of the window (tuple addition)
    newshape += norm_shape(ws)


    # the strides tuple will be the array's strides multiplied by step size, plus
    # the array's strides (tuple addition)
    newstrides = norm_shape(np.array(a.strides) * ss) + a.strides
    a = ast(a,shape = newshape,strides = newstrides)
    if not flatten:
        return a
    # Collapse strided so that it has one more dimension than the window.  I.e.,
    # the new array is a flat list of slices.
    meat = len(ws) if ws.shape else 0
    firstdim = (np.product(newshape[:-meat]),) if ws.shape else ()
    dim = firstdim + (newshape[-meat:])
    # remove any dimensions with size 1
    dim = filter(lambda i : i != 1,dim)

    return a.reshape(dim), newshape

def CreateRaster(xx,yy,std,gt,proj,driverName,outFile):  
    '''
    Exports data to GTiff Raster
    '''
    std = np.squeeze(std)
    std[np.isinf(std)] = -99
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(driverName)
    rows,cols = np.shape(std)
    ds = driver.Create( outFile, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)      
    if proj is not None:  
        ds.SetProjection(proj.ExportToWkt()) 
    ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)
    ss_band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    ss_band.WriteArray(std)
    ss_band.SetNoDataValue(-99)
    ss_band.FlushCache()
    ss_band.ComputeStatistics(False)
    del ds


#Stuff to change

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    win_sizes = [7]
    for win_size in win_sizes[:]:   
        in_raster = #Path to input raster
        win = win_size
        meter = str(win/4)

        #Define output file names
        contFile = 
        dissFile = 
        homoFile = 
        energyFile = 
        corrFile =
        ASMFile = 



        merge, xx, yy, gt = read_raster(in_raster)

        merge[np.isnan(merge)] = 0

        Z,ind = sliding_window(merge,(win,win),(win,win))

        Ny, Nx = np.shape(merge)

        w = Parallel(n_jobs = cpu_count(), verbose=0)(delayed(p_me)(Z[k]) for k in xrange(len(Z)))

        cont = [a[0] for a in w]
        diss = [a[1] for a in w]
        homo = [a[2] for a in w]
        eng  = [a[3] for a in w]
        corr = [a[4] for a in w]
        ASM  = [a[5] for a in w]


        #Reshape to match number of windows
        plt_cont = np.reshape(cont , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        plt_diss = np.reshape(diss , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        plt_homo = np.reshape(homo , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        plt_eng = np.reshape(eng , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        plt_corr = np.reshape(corr , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        plt_ASM =  np.reshape(ASM , ( ind[0], ind[1] ) )
        del cont, diss, homo, eng, corr, ASM

        #Resize Images to receive texture and define filenames
        contrast = im_resize(plt_cont,Nx,Ny)
        contrast[merge==0]=np.nan
        dissimilarity = im_resize(plt_diss,Nx,Ny)
        dissimilarity[merge==0]=np.nan    
        homogeneity = im_resize(plt_homo,Nx,Ny)
        homogeneity[merge==0]=np.nan
        energy = im_resize(plt_eng,Nx,Ny)
        energy[merge==0]=np.nan
        correlation = im_resize(plt_corr,Nx,Ny)
        correlation[merge==0]=np.nan
        ASM = im_resize(plt_ASM,Nx,Ny)
        ASM[merge==0]=np.nan
        del plt_cont, plt_diss, plt_homo, plt_eng, plt_corr, plt_ASM


        del w,Z,ind,Ny,Nx

        driverName= 'GTiff'    
        epsg_code=26949
        proj = osr.SpatialReference()
        proj.ImportFromEPSG(epsg_code)

        CreateRaster(xx, yy, contrast, gt, proj,driverName,contFile) 
        CreateRaster(xx, yy, dissimilarity, gt, proj,driverName,dissFile)
        CreateRaster(xx, yy, homogeneity, gt, proj,driverName,homoFile)
        CreateRaster(xx, yy, energy, gt, proj,driverName,energyFile)
        CreateRaster(xx, yy, correlation, gt, proj,driverName,corrFile)
        CreateRaster(xx, yy, ASM, gt, proj,driverName,ASMFile)

        del contrast, merge, xx, yy, gt, meter, dissimilarity, homogeneity, energy, correlation, ASM
```

This script calculates GLCM properties for a defined window size, with no overlap between adjacent windows.

Comment: Could you expand on what the greycomatrix parameters do? Im not sure what 'distances', 'angles' or 'levels' mean in the documentation and how the results will behave if I change them

Comment: [Here](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/tutorial.htm) is a good tutorial I used to learn about GLCM's and [here](http://haralick.org/journals/TexturalFeaturesHaralickShanmugamDinstein.pdf) is the seminal paper where they were first published.  I find the paper fascinating, considering it was published in 1973.  In short, distances', 'angles' or 'levels'  are GLCM calculation parameters.  Ideal values are application specific.

Comment: @dubbbdan could you comment on your use of RectBivariateSpline? Why do you need to use it, what does it do. Does it improve calculation times or the results in some way?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye Its been a while since I have thought about this. I think it had to do with its ability to efficiently interpolate between floats with high levels precision.  Looking back, it seems like this is a rather complex approach to a simple problem of interpolating GLCM texture metrics.  Thise numbers are much simpler than lat/long values that the algorithm was originally intended for.